# How to write Hashable protocol yourself in swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Is there a way to make custom protocols be propagative like standard `Hashable`, `Equatable`, `Codable` and so on i.e. when all properties of a `struct`/`class` conform to the protocol then the `struct`/`class` itself can conform to that protocol.

Say I have a simple protocol like this:

```swift
protocol State {
    init()
}
```

Suppose I have two structs:

```swift
struct State1: State {}
struct State2: State {}
```

They conform to the protocol, then I want to have another `struct` conforming to my protocol like this:

```swift
struct AppState: State {  // error: Type 'AppState' does not conform to protocol 'State'
    let state1: State1
    let state2: State2
}
```

In theory if all properties has an empty `init()` then it should be no problem implicitly implementing init in the `AppState` struct. But the compiler only understand an explicit `init()` in `AppState`. So is there a way to enhance my protocol `State` to have that feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, this isn't meaningfully possible in Swift at the moment. Automatic conformance to protocols is currently limited to being implemented directly in the compiler (see, e.g., the [implementation for `Codable`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/lib/Sema/DerivedConformanceCodable.cpp), and [`Equatable` and `Hashable`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/lib/Sema/DerivedConformanceEquatableHashable.cpp)); the only way you'd be able to hook into this mechanism would be to add direct support to the compiler — feasible if you're willing to fork the compiler and use that to compile all of your code, but that's a pretty big leap.

Comment: Oh wow. I though that there are some shenanigans definitely going on in there, but I didn't think that these protocols are so fundamental in swift they're literally supported by the compiler. And what about `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` in this case, they are also working with raw types, do they also rely on the compiler?

Comment: Just to be clear: protocols like `Hashable` are still [_defined_ in Swift code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Hashable.swift), but the automatic conformance portion of it is what currently still requires compiler support (the language doesn't yet have the tools to define the semantics in-source).

Comment: `JSONEncoder`/`JSONDecoder` themselves don't need any compiler support; they don't need anything the language itself can't offer both at compile time and run time — you can see their pure Swift implementation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift).